# iframe designmode = "on" ie., in deep div

Tags: javascript, html, iframe, designmode

I have "mypage.html" which contains

```
<div id = "more">
 <div id = "content">
  </div>
 </div>
```

> ```
>   where <div id = "content"> contains another html page 
>   I have accessed it using jquery in "mypage.html"
>   the code is
> ```

```
 $(document).ready(function(){
    $("#content_window").load("otherpage.html");   
});
```

> where "otherpage.html" contains

```
<div id = "question>
  <div id = "box">
    <div id = "richtextare">
      <iframe id = "wysiwyg" name = "wysiwyg">
      </iframe>
     </div>
   </div>
 </div>
```

Where "Elements" is "DevTools" in chrome  showing up the elements like this

```
<div id = "more">
 <div id = "content">
  <div id = "question>
   <div id = "box">
    <div id = "richtextare">
    <iframe id = "wysiwyg" name = "wysiwyg">
    </iframe>
   </div>
  </div>
  </div>
 </div>
</div>
```

> Now how can i "on" the design mode of "iframe". When i use

```
 var richeditor = wysiwyg.document;
       richeditor.designMode = "on";
```

design mode is working in "otherpage.html" but it is not working in "mypage.html"